i can't connect to realtime local supabase
i can't connect to locally realtime supabase .i think URL or supabase-key wrong. error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kk/supabase-kubernetes/charts/supabase/PUB/PUB.py", line 66, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())   
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/kk/supabase-kubernetes/charts/supabase/PUB/PUB.py", line 51, in main
    await client.connect()
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/realtime/_async/client.py", line 126, in connect
    self.ws_connection = await websockets.connect(self.url)
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 655, in __await_impl_timeout__
    return await self.__await_impl__()
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 662, in __await_impl__
    await protocol.handshake(
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 329, in handshake
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code, response_headers)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 404

I have deployed Supabase locally in Kubernetes. Then, I used the realtime-py library to enable Supabase's real-time functionality in Python using the following code
import asyncio
from realtime import AsyncRealtimeClient, RealtimeSubscribeStates
from kubemq.queues import Client, QueueMessage
import json
import os
from typing import Optional
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging

load_dotenv()

URL: str = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_URL")
SUPABASE_KEY : str = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_KEY")
CHANNEL: str = os.environ.get("CHANNEL")
ADDRESS: str = os.environ.get("ADDRESS")
CHANNEL_NAME: str = os.environ.get("CHANNEL_NAME")

async def main():

    client = AsyncRealtimeClient(URL, SUPABASE_KEY)
    await client.connect()
    channel_1 = client.channel(CHANNEL_NAME)
    channel_1.on_postgres_changes("INSERT",schema="public",callback=callback1)
    await channel_1.subscribe(_on_subscribe)
    await client.listen()
    await client.close()

asyncio.run(main())   

URL for locally in realtime-py Docs is "ws://localhost:4000/socket" but i forward path to "http://localhost:52102" So my URl is "ws://localhost:52102/socket" and my supabase-key i think that is service-key .So my supabase-key is  service-key .that correct or not .help me please
